# how can I correct my code to make this AppBarButton stretshes in the CommandBar

Tags: xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I am trying to stretch the AppBarButton in my SecondaryCommands with this Style:

```
<Style x:Key="AppBarButtonStyle1" TargetType="AppBarButton">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="68"/>
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="AppBarButton">
                <Grid x:Name="Root" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding MaxWidth}" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="FullSize"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Compact">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Overflow">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="OverflowWithToggleButtons">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentRoot">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="38,0,12,0"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListLowBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListMediumBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseHighBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Content">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="InputModeStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="InputModeDefault"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="TouchInputMode">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="OverflowTextLabel.Padding" Value="0,11,0,13"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="ContentRoot" MinHeight="{ThemeResource AppBarThemeCompactHeight}">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="20" Margin="0,14,0,4"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TextLabel" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="12" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" Margin="0,0,0,6" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{TemplateBinding Label}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="OverflowTextLabel" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="15" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="12,0,12,0" Padding="0,5,0,7" TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{TemplateBinding Label}" TextTrimming="Clip" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and this is what I did in my xaml file:

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Label="Forward" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle1}"HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
        </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

and this is what I get:
[image]

So how can I correct my code to make this AppBarButton stretch in the CommandBar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want your AppBarButton looks like following:
[image]

If so, you can set the `HorizontalAlignment` property in your `Style` and change its `Value` to `Stretch` and more important change the value of `Width` to `Auto` like:

```xml
<Style x:Key="AppBarButtonStyle1" TargetType="AppBarButton">
    ...
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
    ...
</Style>
```